# Regex conversion issue

Tags: php, regex

I was given a regex to search through logs with. However, it works in their search but not in PHP. I'm bad with regex, and have no clue what’s wrong with it.

Their regex `"\\] ([a-zA-Z _]+) \\(.*to ([a-zA-Z _]+) \\(.*\\$([0-9,]+)"`

```
Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

I need assistance in getting this to work in PHP.

An example of the logs is:

```
[2013/12/28 - 15:16:22] Zack Willson (IP: 127.0.0.1) has sold their house (ID 4681) to William Hill (IP: 127.0.0.1) for $13,700,000.
```

I need to obtain the first players name, the second players name, and the amount it cost. If that regex isn't easily converted or whatever the issue may be.

Comment: In what system their regex is used?

Comment: The solution to your immediate problem is that preg_match expects a regex to be surrounded by delimiters, which as it says, can't be a backslash.  Forward slash is pretty typical, such as:  `"/\\] ([a-zA-Z _]+) \\(.*to ([a-zA-Z _]+) \\(.*\\$([0-9,]+)/"`

Comment: I honestly have no clue, all I know is it worked properly in [link](http://puu.sh/620lV/64bfe7f941.png) screenshot

Comment: Remember you can most always google error messages: [Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+Delimiter%20must%20not%20be%20alphanumeric%20or%20backslash)

Comment: @femtoRgon - Thank you, but I tried that and it only gets the full string. However the errors stop with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this regex:

```
\]\s+([a-zA-Z\s_]+)\s+\(.*\)\s+to\s+([a-zA-Z\s_]+)\s+.*\)\s+for\s+(\$[0-9,\s_]+)\s?+
```

In PHP it would be:

```
// Test data from the log.
$log_data = "[2013/12/28 - 15:16:22] Zack Willson (IP: 127.0.0.1) has sold their house (ID 4681) to William Hill (IP: 127.0.0.1) for $13,700,000.";

// The 'preg_match' statement.
preg_match('/\]\s+([a-zA-Z\s_]+)\s+\(.*\)\s+to\s+([a-zA-Z\s_]+)\s+.*\)\s+for\s+(\$[0-9,\s_]+)\s?+/is', $log_data, $matches);

// Output the '$matches'
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the results would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ] Zack Willson (IP: 127.0.0.1) has sold their house (ID 4681) to William Hill (IP: 127.0.0.1) for $13,700,000
    [1] => Zack Willson
    [2] => William Hill
    [3] => $13,700,000
)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up using. I tried to mark my question answered but I couldn't yet.
Thank you